# Error passing custom object between activities through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried passing this simple object from MainActivity to Main2Activity by implementing Serializable on the CustomObject. It results in Error. I referred the similar stack overflow questions. Nothing helped.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String TAG = "MainActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("data",new CustomObject());
//I tried i.putExtra(bundle);
    i.putExtra("data",new CustomObject());
    startActivity(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
}

public class CustomObject implements Serializable{
    public int i = 0;
    public int j = 9;
    CustomObject(){

    }
}
}
```

Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
String TAG = "Main2Activity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    MainActivity.CustomObject c = (MainActivity.CustomObject)i.getSerializableExtra("data");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+c.i+" "+c.j);
}
}
```

Error Message:

> 07-30 13:58:58.352 26489-26489/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                  Process: gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt, PID: 26489
>                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt/gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name =
>   gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity$CustomObject)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2684)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
>                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name =
>   gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity$CustomObject)
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
>                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1417)
>                                                      at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
>                                                      at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8703)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082)
>                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4229)
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4526)
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4494)
>                                                      at gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684)
>                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637)
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
>                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity
>                                                      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
>                                                      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
>                                                      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
>                                                      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
>                                                      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
>                                                      at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522)
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) 
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
>                                                      at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1417) 
>                                                      at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
>                                                      at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
>                                                      at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8703) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082) 
>                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520) 
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4229) 
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187) 
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4526) 
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4494) 
>                                                      at gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21) 
>                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6684) 
>                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2637) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
>                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
>                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by this error in logs:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: gct.venkatesh.com.scrshtrebuilt.MainActivity at
```

`MainActivity` is not *Serializable*, i think platform wants `MainActivity` to be serializable because `CustomObject` is inner class in `MainActivity` ,

try to define your `CustomObject` in a separate local class (separate file)

Comment: That works fine. But I have a doubt. When I try serializing a custom object and sending it as a broadCast it works well even if the outer class doesn't implement serializable. Why is that while sending it to another activity it is not serializable. Also note that when I send object as broadcast I sent from a service. Even from service startActivity(intent) doent serialize

Comment: @Venkatesh how do you send it in the Broadcast? do you use same method `putSerializable()` ?

Comment: also this could be related to `Activity` as MainActivity extends it, but in your other case, what does your outer class extends (if it extends anything?) **i am not sure** just guessing :)

Comment: Yes same putSerializable() is used. It worked fine. Outer class is a child of  Service.